# Making the whole row clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I was trying to make a whole row of my tables on jsp page clickable for it i wrote following code in jsp page :

```
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.beans.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/clickablerow.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>MY DATA</title>
</head>
<body>
<%!Connection con; %>
<%!PreparedStatement s; %>
<%!ResultSet rs; %>

<% String name=request.getParameter("q");
//out.println(name);
try{
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:SharedCryptography", "fyp", "fyp");

String groupidd = request.getSession().getAttribute("groupid").toString();

//out.println(groupidd);
/*String sql="select * from tbIndividual where I_NAME like ? "
        + "and I_ID in "
        + "(select I_ID from TBWAITINDIVIDUALS "
        + "where GROUP_ID <> '"+groupidd+"')";
*/
String sql="select * from tbIndividual where I_NAME like ?";




s = con.prepareStatement(sql);
s.setString(1, name + "%");
rs=s.executeQuery();
}
catch(Exception e){ 
e.printStackTrace(); 
}
%>

<div id="dtl_table"><table border='3' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='2' width="400px">
<tr bgcolor="66FF00">

<th>ID</th>
<th>NAME</th>
<th>FIRSTNAME</th>
<th>LASTNAME</th>
</tr>

    
<% while(rs.next())
{ %>
<%String storid=rs.getString(1);%>
<tr class="clickableRow" href="individualdetailstoadd.jsp?personid=<%=storid%>">
<td><%=storid%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(4)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(5)%></td>
</tr>
<tr/>
<% } %>
</tr>
</table></div>

</body>
</html>
```

And included

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/clickablerow.js"></script>
```

at top of the page and in clickablerow.js i wrote :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".clickableRow").click(function() {
        window.document.location = $(this).attr("href");
  });
});
```

Am I doing something wrong? As this is not working.

Comment: Do you have your browser's developer console open? If so, are you getting errors? There could be many different things wrong. The code as you show it is correct. Also, show the rendered HTML.

Comment: Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JUn34/ Your code works just fine.

Comment: @cookiemonster you are assigning each row seperatley i dont want that .

Comment: @cookiemonster i had put my whole jsp page.Please check where i am wrong.Thanx in advance.

Comment: assigning to each row separately? What do you mean? The handler? Why not?

Comment: Why are your script tags are outside the document?

Comment: ...and you said the rows are added dynamically after the page loads. Where's the JavaScript code that adds them?

Comment: @cookiemonster javascript code is kept in js folder with name clickablerow.js

Comment: I don't see any JavaScript in the question that adds rows to the page dynamically. I only see JavaScript that assigns the `click` handler after the document is ready.

Comment: @cookiemonster by dynamically i mean that depending on my resultset the count of rows changes

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you can reduce your jQuery ready call to:

```
$(function() {
}
```

its the exact same.

now, i think you would want to delegate your click handler, meaning you attach it to the document instead, so the document will search for the clickable row and handle its click events:

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on("click",".clickableRow",function() {
        window.document.location = $(this).attr("href");
  });
});
```

Comment: Your `.ready()` call is a little different in that you're using the global `$` with no local reference, whereas the original uses the global `jQuery` and defines a local `$` just in case `window.$` is overwritten.

Comment: @Banana I didnt get you.?you are saying to replace the function is js file by this function?and what about the jsp page ??

Comment: ...and if you're going to use `document` level delegation *(though I'm not sure why that's needed here)*, there's no need for a `.ready()` call at all.

Comment: @cookie monster, yep no need for ready call, its just easier to understand where to put it that way thats all.

Comment: @OP yes, replace your function with this, also make sure you link your jQuery library before you link your clickablerow.js

Comment: @Banana and what about <tr class="clickableRow" href="individualdetailstoadd.jsp?personid=<%=storid%>">
?Is this ok ?

Comment: @OP you said your redirection doesnt work, does it not redirect at all? or redirects to a wrong place? if it redirects to a wrong place then no, this line is not ok. and if it doesnt redirect at all, then the problem is with the jQuery

Comment: @user3462609: This solution would only be used if the rows are dynamically added after the page has loaded. That doesn't seem to be the case in your question. You need to provide more information.

Comment: @cookiemonster the rows are added dynamically.And which libraray to include to use jquery?Also in tr tag the link is fine but am asking is class="clickableRow ok ?

Comment: @OP you can download jQuery from http://jquery.com/download/ and add it to your website + link as you would any other js file. make sure to link jQuery before **ANY** other code that utilizes jQuery

Comment: @user3462609: Why isn't that in the question??? Then take take this approach, but bind the handler to the `table`, or the nearest ancestor that is not added to the page dynamically.

Comment: @Banana: Your `.on()` syntax is turned around. The event type comes first.

Comment: @Banana i added <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> at the top.But it still dont work

Comment: check your developer console for errors. does it say that '$' is undefined? or anything else in red ?

Answer (score 0):

`href` is a wrong attribute for `tr`

You can use the concept of `data`

### Example:

Prefix href with data

```
<tr class="clickableRow" data-href="
```

Write JQuery as below

```
$(".clickableRow").click(function() {
        window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
});
```